# Display object.responseXML text for debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, debugging, sharepoint

I'm using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function processResult(xData, status) { 
       $('.feedbackLink').empty(); 
        alert ($(xData.responseXML.xml));
        console.log($(xData.responseXML.xml));
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() { 
            alert ($(this));
            var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title"); 
            var url = $(this).attr("ows_Contact"); 
            $('.feedbackLink').append("<a href="+url+">"+title+"</a>"); 
       }); 

   };

   $(document).ready(function() { 
   alert("ready"); 
       var soapEnv = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> <soapenv:Body> <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> <listName>Pages</listName> <viewFields> <ViewFields> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <FieldRef Name='Contact' /> </ViewFields> </viewFields> </GetListItems> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>";       
       $.ajax({ 
           url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx", 
           type: "POST", 
           dataType: "xml", 
           data: soapEnv, 
           complete: processResult, 
           contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"" 
       });
       alert(soapEnv); 
   }); 

    </script>
```

But the alert within `$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {` wont fire. How can I view the responseXML? I want to double check I'm looking for the right identifiers (I dont know where the `ows_` came from, I was given this script to work with).

The alert and console.log just displays [object Object].

Any advice on how to debug this?

Comment: What browser are you using to bring this up in?

Comment: I'm using IE8 as the standard here, but have access to firefox as well. I'm trying to use the IE debugger at the moment but it also just returns [object Object]

Comment: Have you installed firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox? If not, can you?

Comment: I have it but didnt check it yet (I mainly use it for CSS) `Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; 'soapenv' is an undeclared namespace. Line 1, position 211.` was in the response. Thanks for your help. Post an answer if you want credit.

Comment: I have moved my comments to the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox to see error messages and messages produced by `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `console.log(xData.responseText)` to get in the console the actual xml instead of [object Object].

Answer (score 3):

in IE:

```
alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
```

in Firefox (unconfirmed):

```
var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xData.responseXML); alert(string);
```

to see the full xml, you can append it to the page (IE):

```
function processResult(xData, status) 
{
    document.body.innerHTML += htmlEncode(xData.responseXML.xml);
}
function htmlEncode(str)
{
    return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

xData.responseXML.xml is the xml as a string, so converting it to a jquery object isnt needed

Comment: yeah, that wasnt for you. except the last line. but even then i just thought i should address the actual question